# Android Connectivity manager

Tags: android, connectivity

I use the following statement

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Also this imports

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
```

Ans this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

But I get this error : The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type Network_Connectivity

Answer (score 4):

getSystemService needs to be called from context or Activity class. Looks like ur Network_Connectivity doesnt extends Activity.

Pass context as a param and try something like this:

```
public void initConnectivityManager(Context c) {    
    Context c = context;
    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
}
```